# Manejo de llaves compuestas en hibernate + netbeans + java

Tags: java, netbeans, hibernate

En una aplicación de escritorio java debo hacer un crud sobre un tabla padre y una hija. La hija tiene una clave compuesta por la clave de la tabla padre y otro campo. Usando netbeans e hibernate he generado los pojos de las dos tablas, pero hibernate también me genera una clase que representa la clave primaria de la tabla hija. No entiendo muy bien, como hacer el crud sobre la tabla hija. Aguién me puede ayudar con un ejemplo sobre como realizar el crud sobre la tabla hija. Agradezco su colaboración

Answer (score 0):

Por la experiencia que tengo yo sobre Hibernate, haz el crud con el pojo la hija con toda la tranquilidad del mundo.

hasta donde yo se, esa classe es la manera que tiene hibernate de entender esa clave compuesta como un concepto unico.

es decir, como esos dos valores forman una clave:

dos valores -->classe --> classe clave que encapsula los dos valores en un "@id"